# OpsCenter agent can't connect to node, returns "TransportException: [/127.0.0.1:9042] Cannot connect"

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise, opscenter

Can't connect to Cassandra (All host(s) tried for query failed (tried: /127.0.0.1:9042 (com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.TransportException: [/127.0.0.1:9042] Cannot connect))), retrying soon.
[image]

on Opscenter log

```
ERROR: Alert for agents with issues on node 192.168.211.2 is currently Fired (MainThread)
```

on node agent.log

```
 INFO [async-dispatch-6] 2023-03-27 09:43:38,279 Starting 
 monitored database connection.
 ERROR [async-dispatch-6] 2023-03-27 09:43:40,490 Can't connect 
 to Cassandra (All host(s) tried for query failed (tried: 
 /127.0.0.1:9042 
 (com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.TransportException: 
 [/127.0.0.1:9042] Cannot connect))), retrying soon.
```

Comment: A friendly reminder that Stack Overflow is for getting help with coding, algorithm, or programming language problems so I voted to have your post moved to [DBA Stack Exchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=cassandra). For future reference, you should post DB admin/ops questions on https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=cassandra. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

what's the version of DataStax Enterprise (DSE) & OpsCenter being used here in this setup? I assume you're using [compatible product versions](https://docs.datastax.com/en/home/docs/compatibility.html#_dse_opscenter_compatibility_with_dse) here.

Also, you may want to ensure you're setting up `opscenterd.conf` (on the OpsCenter machine), `address.yaml` (on the DSE node itself) correctly with the correct IPs to use. If you've already followed all the [set up instructions from here](https://docs.datastax.com/en/opscenter/docs/6.8/online_help/opscClusterAdmin_c.html) and if you've a valid DSE subscription license, you may create a support ticket [**DataStax Support portal**](https://support.datastax.com) by uploading `opscenterd.conf`, `opscenterd.log`, `address.yaml`, `agent.log`, `cassandra.yaml`, and `dse.yaml` to get started with the triage.

Answer (score 0):

It appears as though you have misconfigured the agent on the node so it cannot connect to the local Cassandra instance.

This error indicates that you've configured the agent to connect to `localhost`:

```
ERROR [async-dispatch-6] 2023-03-27 09:43:40,490 Can't connect 
 to Cassandra (All host(s) tried for query failed (tried: 
 /127.0.0.1:9042 
 (com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.TransportException: 
 [/127.0.0.1:9042] Cannot connect))), retrying soon.
```

Connecting to `127.0.0.1` is a mistake because it doesn't make sense for a DSE node to be listening for client connections on `localhost`. It needs to be set to the same IP as the `native_transport_address` in `cassandra.yaml`.

If you've manually configured the `address.yaml` for the agent, review it particularly for the `hosts` property which should NOT be set to `127.0.0.1`. We recommend that you let OpsCenter automatically configure the agents. Cheers!